# Why does this code print lines and not single chars

Tags: c, putchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
  putchar(c);
  return 0;
}
```

In my limited exposure to C,as long as C!=EOF the while condition will get executed which essentially will print c and then wait for the next char and try to examine of that does or does not violate the condition. Hence for each char we put enter the putchar will execute.
However when I ran the executable what seemed to happen was the print statement would work only when I pressed for new line (Enter) and it had a buffer of some sort which would print the whole line in the input.
I fail to see any buffer in the code that will hold the chars until a new line is pressed,so what is being done here ?
Where is these chars getting stored until a new line is pressed ?

Comment: In your terminal, and after hitting enter,  in the `FILE` struct used for standard input.

Comment: How do you distinguish you are reading chars in line chunks or individually?  Your program works very quick and probably doesn't give you a chance to see how it is proceeding.  The terminal works in line mode to allow you to edit the input before sending it to the program.  See my answer for a more complete explanation.

Comment: "so what is being done here" Your terminal/console/whatever is being smart and letting you edit your input before sending it to the program. "Where is these chars getting stored until a new line is pressed" In the terminal driver. In addition there are buffers (that you can disable) in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

When reading from the console like this, your program does not actually receive any input at all until you press enter, and then it reads and processes the entire line at once.

Your program has no idea that those characters even exist until you press enter, at which point they are sent to the stdin buffer. From here, your loop will read and print each character (including the new line) until either the buffer is empty (meaning it will wait for more input), or the end of file is reached.

Answer (score 1):

The buffering is happening in the the reading of data **and** the writing of data.

`stdin` and `stdout`, independently can be *character*, *line* or *fully* buffered.

In your common case, both are *line* buffered.

Input is not given to `getchar()` until <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`'\n'`) is hit. (Can you back-space input?)   and output is not displayed until a `'\n'` is printed.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Backspace handling and the like is independent of buffering. It happens outside of the program. The input is nit given to *the program* until enter is hit. Buffering happens on top of this.

Comment: @n.m. "The input is nit given to the program until enter is hit." --> That is a possible, though not required implementation (it is quite common). The "Can you back-space input?" was for OP to try and see that the key before and the backspace key likely did not show up in `stdin` and therefore evidence that buffering of input is happening _someplace_ and not just in output as OP suggests.

Comment: Almost nothing is required. It is not required that a terminal is an "interactive device" for example. I'm talking about the real situation rather than any possible situation allowed by the standard.

Comment: @n.m. "The input is nit given to the program until enter is hit." is often not so with real life piped input.

Comment: I'm not interesting in inventing all kinds of scenarios which would explain this behaviour. I'm going with the one that has occurred in actual factual actuality. The user was running a program in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The `getchar()` and `putchar()` functions are part of `stdio` package, that makes buffered input/output.

This means that, despite of the number of characters you actually request (one only in your case) the buffering mechanism makes the characters to wait in the buffer until a whole buffer (or one line, in case `stdin` comes from a tty device) is filled.

What is happening here is that, on first `getchar()` a full buffer fill is requested, and filled only partially with the input line you keyed in.  After that, all the `getchar()` calls take individual characters from the buffer, until it is empty again, and at that time, another full buffer is requested.

This is made to make single char processing an efficient way of processing.  That also happens on output.  The `putchar()` function only fills the buffer, until it is completely full (or, in case your output channel is to a tty device, until you request to output a `\n` character) and when it is, the full buffer is output to the file/device.

Also, the terminal driver in all flavours of unix, works in line mode, what means that until you press the `<ENTER>` key, you don't get anything sent to the program.  This will allow you to correct mistakes made on keying, by the use of the erase key (backspace) and/or the kill (Cntrl-U) keys.  This is simulated in Windows console applications, so you'll probably need the output device into raw mode before being able to input in a character based way.

If you want to make your program to read one character at a time, you need to bypass the buffers of stdio (via `setbuf(NULL)` function  call, or using the `read(2)` system call to read one character, which can be done with:

```
char c;
int res = read(0, &c, 1);
if (res < 0) { /* error */
    ...
} else if (res == 0) { /* EOF in input */
    ...
} else { /* 1, as you requested only one char */
    ... /* one character was read. */
}
```

) and to put the terminal driver in raw mode (via `tcsetattr()` and `tcgetattr()` calls, see `termios(4)` manual page for details on how to do this) before you do actual reading.  In this case, you must return the terminal state to line mode before terminating the program, or you will run into trouble.